# To prove $\gcd\{p^2-1: p $ is a prime $ \geq 7 \}=24$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function

Let $p$ be a prime $\geq 7$.

$p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$. Both $(p-1)$ and $(p+1)$ are divisible by $2$ and they are two consecutive even numbers. So, either one of the two must be divisible by $4$. So, $8 \mid (p^2-1)$. Again, by Euler's theorem, $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod3$. Thereby, $24 \mid (p^2-1)$, for all prime $p \geq 7$.

To prove that $24$ is the greatest common divisor:

For $p=7$, $p^2-1=48$. So, the only other possible $\gcd$ is going to be $48$. But for $p=11$, $p^2-1=120$ and $48 \nmid 120$.

Therefore $\gcd\{p^2-1: p $  is a prime $ \geq 7 \}=24$.

Is this correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DZMkIiFs35HQ&ved=2ahUKEwiM6Pvsza3kAhUxSN8KHZ4SDJcQwqsBMAB6BAgEEAU&usg=AOvVaw1XoFlHrOW2tdcnMYwLQJj4

Comment: numberphile has a video on this problem

Comment: Whoah... checked the video. :)

Comment: Umm, doesn't a greatest *common* factor require two numbers? If one is $p^2-1$, what's the other?

Comment: @RhysHughes, we are taking the gcd of all of the primes of the form $p^2-1$, $p$ being the set of all primes $\geq 7$

Comment: gcd of primes is 1. You can't even state your own question correctly.

Comment: * of all the numbers of the form $p^2-1$. If $p$ is a prime larger than $2$,  $p^2-1$ is never a prime. Ignore the typo.